# Regular expression to extract numbers before "."

Tags: regex

I want to extract the number from a file name.

For example, from "`i2mage001.png`", I want to extract "`i2mage`" and "`001`".

I do not know if it will always be the last three numbers which I want to extract. It will be sufficient if I can just extract the numbers, although a regular expression to extract the "`i2mage`" would also be helpful

Comment: `(.*?)([\d]+)\..*`?

Comment: `I do not know if it will always be the last three numbers which I want to extract.` <- I suggest you make a list of strings that you may possibly receive. Like numbers in the middle, numbers at the end, give more information on which parts you want, etc.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: The answer is already given. Follow @devnull comment

Comment: @nurettin What I meant is that it might be "image0001" or "image00001" etc.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(.+?)(\d+)\.png
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/aI5tB2

Comment: Thanks. The solution posted by @devnull is a bit more generic as he used any file extension (not just png). But he didn't post it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

This regex matches the digits part (without groups - ie the entire match is your target):

```
\d+(?=\.)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/x7jF7mvtnr).

---

And this matches the part before that (ie `i2image` in your example):

```
.*\D(?=\d+\.)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/IefyeXPFpn).